# Php Magic Method __get __set - how to set boundaries on specific fields but not others

Tags: php, methods, setter, getter

I have a class of entirely private variables; only certain variables will need some data validation on the way in.

Right now I have:

```
public class Example 
{
    //**** Variables / Properties ****/
    private $one;
    private $two; 
    private $three;

    //**** getter **** // 
    public function __get( $property ) 
    {
        if(property_exists($this,$property) { 
             return $this->$property;
        }
    }

    // **** setter **** //
    public function __set($property, $value) 
    {
         if(property_exists($this,$property)) {
            $this->$property = $value;
         }
    }
}
```

What if I want to do data validation on $two but just return $one and $three without any data validation?
I ask this because my class has many more variables than this and I hate writing individual set and get methods for every property of the class when only some of them require specific behavior.

Comment: Either  put them in your __get() method and have a control structure determine if validation is needed. Otherwise, make getters for them.

Comment: @JohnConde Don't know why I didn't think of that. Maybe just have a big switch statement within that get and set method. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out with the help of @JohnConde.

First declare which fields need to be validated in an array.

```
private $dateArr = array("two");
```

Then

```
public function __set($property,$value) {
    if(property_exists($this,$property)) {
         foreach($dateArr as $dateProperty) {
              if($property == $dateProperty) {
                    cleanDate($property,$value);
                    return;
                  }
            }
                return $this->$property;
      }
}
```

What this does is delegates specific fields off to be validated, but returns others as they are.
This is beneficial because I don't have to write the getters and setters manually.